# When calling SonarQube API - /api/properties?format=json - results in a Ruby error

Tags: ruby, sonarqube

I'm attempting to set up the SonarLint IntelliJ IDEA plugin (plugin for SonarQube) and it's failing due to a 500 response when the plugin calls the following URL:

```
/api/properties?format=json
```

When I go to either `/api/properties` or `/api/properties?format=xml` in my browser, things look okay.  However, when I go to `/api/properties?format=json` I see the following in my sonar.log file:

```
2016.10.03 09:37:22 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://jenkins.aws.cappex.com:9000/api/properties?format=json
undefined method 'generate' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x344bc254>
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:223:in 'generate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:470:in 'JSON'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:48:in 'jsonp'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/properties_controller.rb:62:in 'index'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in 'call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:135:in 'custom'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in 'call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:179:in 'respond'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in 'each'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:173:in 'respond'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:107:in 'respond_to'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/properties_controller.rb:61:in 'index'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in 'send'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in 'perform_action'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in 'call_filters'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in 'perform_action_with_filters'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in 'perform_action_with_benchmark'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in 'ms'
    jar:file:/etc/sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in 'realtime'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in 'ms'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in 'perform_action_with_benchmark'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in 'perform_action_with_rescue'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in 'perform_action_with_flash'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in 'send'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in 'process'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in 'process_with_filters'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in 'process'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in 'dispatch'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in 'dispatch'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in '_call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in 'build_middleware_stack'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in 'call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in 'cache'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in 'cache'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:67:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in 'call'
    file:/etc/sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in 'context'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in 'call'
    file:/etc/sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in 'serve_rails'
    file:/etc/sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in 'call'
    file:/etc/sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in 'call'

2016.10.03 09:37:22 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://jenkins.aws.cappex.com:9000/api/properties?format=json
undefined method 'generate' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x183f78a8>
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:223:in 'generate'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:470:in 'JSON'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:48:in 'jsonp'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:132:in 'error_to_json'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:123:in 'render_response'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in 'call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:135:in 'custom'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in 'call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:179:in 'respond'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in 'each'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:173:in 'respond'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:107:in 'respond_to'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:122:in 'render_response'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:85:in 'render_error'
    org/jruby/RubyMethod.java:128:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb:73:in 'rescue_with_handler'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:73:in 'rescue_action'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:162:in 'perform_action_with_rescue'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in 'perform_action_with_rescue'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in 'perform_action_with_flash'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in 'send'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in 'process'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in 'process_with_filters'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in 'process'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in 'dispatch'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in 'dispatch'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in '_call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in 'build_middleware_stack'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in 'call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in 'cache'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in 'cache'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:67:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in 'call'
    file:/etc/sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in 'context'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in 'call'
    /etc/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in 'call'
    file:/etc/sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in 'serve_rails'
    file:/etc/sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in 'call'
    file:/etc/sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in 'call'
```

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you running on? Looks like the SonarQube installation had got conflicts with local Ruby gems...

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam - I'm running SonarQube version 5.6.1.

Comment: Can you try to `unset GEM_PATH GEM_HOME RAILS_ENV` before starting server ?

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource - Looks like that did it!  Can you tell me what that command does and why/how that fixed my issue?  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRuby is packaged within SonarQube. It conflicts with local installation of ruby.

Removing the environment variables GEM_PATH, GEM_HOME and RAILS_ENV when starting SonarQube fixes the issue as it hides the ruby installation.
Command is `unset GEM_PATH GEM_HOME RAILS_ENV`.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but could that impact other things on the same server (as the SonarQube installation) that rely on Ruby?  So far, I haven't seen any issues but I'm curious.  Thank you.

Comment: No other impacts if you unset the env variables only in the context of SonarQube, not globally.